# How to get Parent Object count while grouping on child using JAVA 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have Below structure

```
class A
{
    List<B> b;
}

class B
{
    List<C> c;
}

class C
{
    int port;
}
```

I want to group by port and get count of Object B ex : *[443 : 2] (2 object of B have C object with port 443)*

Comment: Show your attempt and clarify what you want to group by port.

Answer (score 0):

The following stream returns the desired value:

```
Map<Integer, Long> countMap = a.getB().stream()
            .flatMap(b -> b.getC().stream().distinct())
            .map(C::getPort)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

`a.getB().stream())` starts a stream of `B`s.
`flatMap(b->b.getC())` flats a stream of `B`s where each element contains `List<C>` to a `Stream` of `C`s and removes duplicates to avoid counting single `B` twice, when it has multiple `C`s with the same port. Make sure, that `C`s equals only compares ports.
Then I `map` each `C` to a port and
`collect`, grouping by `int port` (it's `identity` now), which becomes a key in the returned `Map` and the count of it's occurences.

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = a.getB().stream()
    .flatMap(x -> x.getC().stream())
    .map(C::getPort)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
```

merge all `C` into one stream and map to `port` and then group by `port`

updated:

```
a.getB().stream()
    .map(x -> x.getC().stream()
        .map(C::getPort)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));``
```

Comment: It group by port and get count of port.  OP says **I want to group by port and get count of Object B**

Answer (score -1):

It depends if B can have duplicated C elements or not.

If B cannot have duplicated C elements:

```
IntStream Integer> ports = a.b.stream().flatMap(bElem -> bElem.c.stream()).map(cElem -> Integer.valueOf(cElem.port));

Map<Integer, Long> countByPort = ports.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
```

If B can have duplicated C elements:

Implement C equals/hashcode methods based on port. Then just do a minor change in the "ports" stream assignment:

```
IntStream Integer> ports = a.b.stream().flatMap(bElem -> bElem.c.stream().distinct()).map(cElem -> Integer.valueOf(cElem.port));
```

Notice the "distinct".

**Edit:** Ok i received for whatever reason negatives. So will try to explain why does this actually count number of Bs for each each specific port, which is what the user asked for. First we just list all ports present on all Bs. Each presence on a B is an entry in the list (so same port will appear as many times as Bs it is included on). Then i just count number of times each port is present on that list. **this is the number of Bs esch port is included on**